# How to display results for each year in a new column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can we show result of each year between the condition dates in separate column?
Can we show '0' for "EQ_no" filed which is not in "Jobs" table.

```
select A.EQ_no,A.Serial_no,sum(J.total_cost)Total_Cost,YEAR(Job_Date) as Job_Year
from Equipment A
left OUTER JOIN Jobs J ON J.EQ_no=A.EQ_no
where J.Job_Date BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/31/2020')
group by  A.EQ_no,A.Serial_no,YEAR(Job_Date)
```

Table :  **Jobs**

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| EQ_no |  Job_Date  | Total_Cost |
+-------+------------+------------+
|  1006 | 01/30/2017 |        250 |
|  1006 | 01/31/2018 |        350 |
|  1006 | 01/01/2019 |        150 |
|  1006 | 02/01/2019 |        322 |
|  1006 | 05/05/2019 |        450 |
|  1006 | 02/02/2020 |        500 |
|  1006 | 02/03/2021 |       1212 |
| 29198 | 02/04/2017 |       3000 |
| 29198 | 02/05/2018 |        250 |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

Table : **Equipment**

```
+-------+-----------+
| EQ_no | Serial no |
+-------+-----------+
| 1006  | MDRSC12   |
| 29198 | FDRSC13   |
|  6218 | REAFC14   |
+-------+-----------+
```

**Result**

```
+-------+-----------+------+------+------+
| EQ_no | Serial no | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
+-------+-----------+------+------+------+
|  1006 | MDRSC12   |  350 |  922 |  500 |
| 29198 | FDRSC13   |  250 |    0 |    0 |
|  6218 | REAFC14   |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+-------+-----------+------+------+------+
```

*SQL Version : 2014*

Answer (score 1):

Add `CASE` statement inside the `SUM` aggregate function.

And use `ISNULL` function to replace the Null values by '0'

```
select A.EQ_no,A.Serial_no,ISNULL(MAX(J.EQ_no),0) AS Job_Eq_No
   ,ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(Job_Date) = 2018 THEN  J.total_cost END),0)[2018]
   ,ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(Job_Date) = 2019 THEN  J.total_cost END),0)[2019]
   ,ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(Job_Date) = 2012 THEN  J.total_cost END),0)[2020]
from Equipment A
left OUTER JOIN Jobs J ON J.EQ_no=A.EQ_no
where J.Job_Date BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/31/2020')
group by  A.EQ_no,A.Serial_no
```

Comment: How can we display "0" other  "EQ_no" from Equipment  which is not in Jobs table ?

Comment: I mean "EQ_no" which not in Jobs table and only available in Equipment table.

Comment: I mean display 0 values for each year when "EQ_no" which not in Jobs table and only available in Equipment table.

Comment: @SamBinHam, Have you tried the updated answer? If then please update the question with your exact expected output.

Comment: @ DineshDB : Yes , I tried it. It skips "6218" which is not in Job Jobs table and available in Equipment table.

Comment: @SamBinHam, Is that you are expected or you need something else?

Comment: That's what I excepted .

Comment: @SamBinHam, Great! Happy to hear!! If you found this answer is fix your problem then accept that answer. It will help others.

Answer (score 0):

First, a `left join` is not needed for your query.

Second, you should be using proper date constants.

Third, you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select e.EQ_no, e.Serial_no,
       sum(case when year(j.job_date) = 2018 then J.total_cost else 0 end) as total_cost_2018,
       sum(case when year(j.job_date) = 2019 then J.total_cost else 0 end) as total_cost_2019,
       sum(case when year(j.job_date) = 2020 then J.total_cost else 90 end) as total_cost_2020
from Equipment e join
     Jobs j
     on J.EQ_no = e.EQ_no
where j.job_date >= '2018-01-01' and
      j.job_date < '2021-01-01' 
group by e.EQ_no, e.Serial_no;
```

Also note that this fixes the `where` clause so the `case` is using the same column.  Your sample data doesn't have a column named `datetime_open`.